# CSS/jQuery library to approximate look&feel of Google News UI?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I like the MAC-like button styles and overall look and feel of the UI elements on the new [Google News](http://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn).

Is there a CSS/jQuery library to approximate that kind of sleek, silvery look?

Answer (score 0):

google web toolkit I guess
http://www.vogella.de/articles/GWT/article.html